# Por qué sigue ejecutandose?

Tags: javascript

El código, tras 4 segundos realiza una función que hace que aparezca un input que por defecto tenía `visibility:hidden.`

Además, cuando se clickea el div con id `contentAfterIntro`, debería NO ejecutar el `setTimeout`, ya que para ejecutar este timeout primera se comprueba si la variable `wasClicked` es igual a 0, y solamente si es igual a 0, lo ejecuta. Entonces cuando clickeo el div, `wasClicked` ***le asigno 1***, entonces no debería ejecutarse, pero aún así lo hace.. Por qué?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",m);

function m(){
  var wasClicked = 0;
  var div = document.getElementById("contentAfterIntro");
  div.addEventListener("click",function(){wasClicked = 1;});
  if(wasClicked === 0) setTimeout(show, 4000);
  else console.log("Timeout was canceled.")

 }
 
 function show(){
   var hiddenbutton = document.getElementById("msg");
   hiddenbutton.style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="button" value="invisible?" id="msg">
  <div id="contentAfterIntro" style="background-color: black; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo. La función `m` solo se ejecuta una vez, al igual que la función `show`

Comment: Eduardo, la ejecucion de `m` es inmediata por lo que no te da tiempo a pulsar el div antes de que se cree el timeout. Has de crear el timeout, y si antes de esos 4 segundos se ha hecho click, entonces cancelarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deberías comprobar el valor de `wasClicked` una vez que se cumple el intervalo del timeout.

Ahora lo compruebas en el momento que lo defines (cuando llamas al método `setTimeout`) y en ese momento el valor es siempre `0`:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",m);

function m(){
  var wasClicked = 0;
  var div = document.getElementById("contentAfterIntro");
  div.addEventListener("click",function(){wasClicked = 1;});
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      if (wasClicked===0) show()
      else console.log("Timeout was canceled.")
    }
    , 4000);
 }
 
 function show(){
   var hiddenbutton = document.getElementById("msg");
   hiddenbutton.style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="button" value="invisible?" id="msg">
  <div id="contentAfterIntro" style="background-color: black; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Otra opción es la de utilizar `clearTimeout` para la cancelación:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",m);

function m(){
  var wasClicked = 0;
  var div = document.getElementById("contentAfterIntro");
  var timeout = setTimeout(show, 4000);
  div.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    console.log('timeout cancelado');
  });
}
 
 function show(){
   var hiddenbutton = document.getElementById("msg");
   hiddenbutton.style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

```html
  <input style="visibility: hidden;" type="button" value="invisible?" id="msg">
  <div id="contentAfterIntro" style="background-color: black; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que debes hacer el guardar el `setTimeout` en una variable, y cuando se le de `click` al `div` parar la ejecución !

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", m);
var running = false;

function m() {
  var div = document.getElementById("contentAfterIntro");
  var tiempo = setTimeout(show, 4000);
  running = true;

  div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (running) {
      clearTimeout(tiempo);
      running = false;
      console.log("Timeout was canceled.")
    }
  });

}

function show() {
  var hiddenbutton = document.getElementById("msg");
  hiddenbutton.style.visibility = "visible";
  running = false;
}
```

```html
<input style="visibility: hidden;" type="button" value="invisible?" id="msg">
<div id="contentAfterIntro" style="background-color: black; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid pink;"></div>
```

Comment: Y para más *perfección* y si ponemos una condicion en el click para que solo lo haga si el timeout esta en ejecucion?. Editado :P espero que no sea molestia

Comment: Estaba haciendolo en mi entorno local para editarlo jejeje pero fuiste más rápido, ahora si quedo perfectamente solucionado ! :D

Comment: Por qué el running en show()

Comment: @EduardoSebastian si miras los comentarios es para tener una variable que indique si el timeout está corriendo o no. para que no haga click en él tras haber aparecido el boton o por si haces multiples click , no repetirse el console.log... para mejorar al maximo el codigo.